# Вопрос про PHP и кодировку UTF-8 (Кракозябры при отправке почты с обратной связи сайта)

Tags: email, php, utf-8

Имя отправителя отображается кракозябрами по типу:

```
СЂСЏР°СЂРІР°СЏСЂРІР°СЂ
```

В частности в почте Яндекс и Oulook, уже не знаю где искать.

```
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'example@yandex.ru';
    $clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
    $clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Пожалуйста, введите Ваше имя.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Пожалуйста, введите настоящий адрес электронной почты.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Пожалуйста, введите Ваше сообщение.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
        // Send email
    $headers =  "From: {$clientName} <{$clientEmail}>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: {$clientEmail}" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расскажите, как вы искали ответ на свой вопрос? Первая ссылка в яндексе по запросу yandex mail utf-8.

Используйте base64_encode и указывайте кодировку.
Многие почтовые клиенты некорректно обрабатывают utf-8 (которая чаще всего используется в php скриптах). Я бы рекомендовал для этого Win-1251.
Чтобы перекодировать текст, используйте iconv.

Тут есть рабочий пример: http://konservs.com/post/отправка-почты-используя-php-mail-15